# How to write Iterator[String] result from mapPartitions into one file?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Spark *and* Scala that is why I am having quite a hard time to get through this.

What I intend to do is to pre-process my data with Stanford CoreNLP using  Spark. I understand that I have to use `mapPartitions` in order to have one `StanfordCoreNLP` instance per partition as suggested in [this thread](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Spark-and-Stanford-CoreNLP-td19654.html). However, I lack of knowledge/understanding how to proceed from here.

In the end I want to train word vectors on this data but for now I would be happy to find out how I can get my processed data from here and write it into another file.

This is what I got so far:

```
import java.util.Properties

import com.google.gson.Gson
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.{LemmaAnnotation, SentencesAnnotation, TokensAnnotation}
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.{Annotation, StanfordCoreNLP}
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap
import masterthesis.code.wordvectors.Review
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

object ReviewPreprocessing {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val resourceUrl = getClass.getResource("amazon-reviews/reviews_Electronics.json")
    val file = sc.textFile(resourceUrl.getPath)

    val linesPerPartition = file.mapPartitions( lineIterator => {

      val props = new Properties()
      props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma")

      val sentencesAsTextList : List[String] = List()
      val pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props)
      val gson = new Gson()

      while(lineIterator.hasNext) {

        val line = lineIterator.next
        val review = gson.fromJson(line, classOf[Review])
        val doc = new Annotation(review.getReviewText)

        pipeline.annotate(doc)

        val sentences : java.util.List[CoreMap] = doc.get(classOf[SentencesAnnotation])
        val sb = new StringBuilder();

        sentences.foreach( sentence => {
          val tokens = sentence.get(classOf[TokensAnnotation])
          tokens.foreach( token => {
            sb.append(token.get(classOf[LemmaAnnotation]))
            sb.append(" ")
          })
        })
        sb.setLength(sb.length - 1)
        sentencesAsTextList.add(sb.toString)
      }

      sentencesAsTextList.iterator
    })       

    System.exit(0)
  }

}
```

How would I e.g. write this result into one single file? The ordering does not matter here - I guess the ordering is lost at this point anyway.

Comment: Look into `RDD.saveAsTextFile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you'd use `saveAsTextFile` right on your `RDD`, you'd end up having as many output files as many partitions you have. In order to have just one you can either coalesce everything into one partition like

```
sc.textFile("/path/to/file")
  .mapPartitions(someFunc())
  .coalesce(1)
  .saveAsTextFile("/path/to/another/file")
```

Or (just for fun) you could get all partitions to driver one by one and save all data yourself.

```
val it = sc.textFile("/path/to/file")
  .mapPartitions(someFunc())
  .toLocalIterator

while(it.hasNext) {
  writeToFile(it.next())
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. The problem was another exception that got thrown. The result is still a directory `/home/user/tmp/preprocessed.txt` that contains a file `part-00000` with the actual content I am interested in. I wonder though how I could name that ^^

Comment: I just realized that `coalesce` will cause the whole thing to run only on one partition. But not *after* ` someFunc()` - it does everything only on one partition - That's actually not what I intended to do.

Comment: How many files do you have without using coalesce? There might be few of them, but just one might have data written.

Comment: To transform it before the coalesce you have to "materialize" that - just call it with some action like count or smth similar. Note, though, that if you call take(5), then it'll process only the first partition, because just one partition is enough to get 5 records. Before count() you have to cache rdd to leave it in memory on spark worker nodes.